# Starting local laravel development server with one command

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing a laravel project for some time now and I have bothered by the amount of steps that I need to take to start my local development server.

I have to run the following commands to run my project.

```
php artisan serve
php artisan websockets:serve
php artisan queue:listen
ng s -o
```

I was wondering what can I do to run my local dev server with less steps. I have tried supervisor but I cannot access `localhost:8000` even though the processes spawns correctly.

Edit: I am using WSL for my project

Comment: You can  paste those commands in a `startup.sh` and then just run that command

Comment: Like @UnderDog said which is more common or you can create your own custom command.

Comment: `startup.sh`, `makefile`, `custom artisan command`, `custom npm command`, etc.

Comment: Though `startup.sh` AFAIK, is for linux systems. If you are using vscode and just want to do one click, you can create custom buttons using Action Buttons plugin.

Comment: why not create your own local vhost? For me, till now supervisor has been enough or use docker.

Comment: I tried to create a startup.sh, but it only runs my artisan serve command

Comment: Try putting a space and a `&` after each command in your .sh file, then try again.

Comment: that solved my problem, seems like I set up my commands wrong

Answer (score 0):

make command file which will content all these commands and only one command will launch its:

```
php artisan make:command StartCommand
```

the file located on "app\console\commands", enter the codes you don't want to be less :

```
public function handle() {
   Artisan::call("serve", []);
   Artisan::call("websockets:serve", []);
   Artisan::call("queue:listen", []);
```

}

don't forget the signature which allow to enter command to launch all this :

```
protected $signature = 'launch:start-all';
```

and on the terminal :

```
php artisan launch:start-all
```